# Symfony2 same UserBundle for 2 applications

Tags: symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle

I just created a web reporting tool for customers, using the FOSUserBundle for authentication.
I now want to develop an other reporting tool on the same server but with a different URI.

The user management will be the same.
Do I really have to re-use the UserBundle I created before, or is there a way to authenticate my users using the first application ?

Thanks a lot :)

Pete

Comment: Are you going to create a second Symfony2 app ? Or just another bundle in the same app ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I need a new sub-domain on the server so I have to create a second app...

Comment: You can use multiple domain and subdomain on the same Symfony app, what is the issue ?

Comment: The issue was that I didn't know that !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be interested by the host requirements in the routing file, take a look :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#adding-a-host-requirement

That means you can scope an entire bundle routing to a certain domain.

Don't specify host requirement to your fos user routing, it will works for every domains.
Then override the login/register/... templates for each domain. You may need to override the controllers too.
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_controllers.md
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.md

Comment: My project has been delayed a little. I'm currently trying to use the host requirements in routing. It seems to work for the moment :)